# Wildcard routes on Krakend CE

Tags: krakend

I am trying to enable the wildcard plugin on Krakend  following the official documentation (https://www.krakend.io/docs/enterprise/endpoints/wildcard/). I am currently using the CE edition, someone knows if there is a similar plugin for this version? And where can I find the plugins available for it, since I was trying to check on **/opt/krakend/plugins** of official **devopsfaith/krakend** docker image but it is empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the wildcard plugin is only available on the Enterprise edition. Check the link you passed that contains "enterprise" in the URL.

All functionalities of the community edition are already embedded in the final binary and there is no need to enable any plugins. Functionalities are activated by declaring its namespace in the extra_config. Plugins are used when you want to extend KrakenD functionalities with your own code. KrakenD Enterprise adds several functionalities through custom plugins, and others using middlewares.